# Creating custom timestamp buckets bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an hourly (timestamp) dataset of events from the past month.
I would like to check the performance of events that occurred between certain hours, group them together and average the results.

For example: AVG income of the hours 23:00-02:00 per user:
So if I have this data set below. I'd like to summarise the coloured rows and then average them (the result should be 218).

I tried NTILE but it couldn't divide the data properly, ignoring the irrelevant hours.

Is there a good way to create these custom buckets using SQL?

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8CoV.png)

Comment: It would help people to answer if you could provide additional information in the form of a minimal reproducible example.  Please check the following link for suggestions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

From description not exactly sure how you want to aggregate. If you provide an example dataset can update answer.

However you can easily achieve this with an AVG and IF statement.

`AVG(IF(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp_field) BETWEEN 0 AND 4, value, NULL) as avg_value`

Using the above you can then group by either day or month to get the aggregation level you want.